# Qt Creator: Multi line text editing

Tags: qt-creator

How can I enable multi line text editing for the Qt Creator as known from Code Blocks or Microsoft Visual Studio. You know when you hold the Shift + Alt Key and then press the Down arrow to select multiple lines. Then you can edit multiple lines by typing.

Comment: As you can see on this page ([Proper column editing](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-7773)) column editing was suggested almost two years ago but it has not been implemented and unfortunately its priority is low.

Answer (score 26):

Figured this out just after starting a bounty:

With the mouse, make sure you've already highlighted a character before holding alt. From here it works exactly like Visual Studio.

With the keyboard, hold shift+alt and move around with the arrow keys. You can move down or up lines.

This is where I got this information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WGCxLIjRNg

Comment: Thanks for the youtube link. But he only shows multi line block deletion. I was looking for multi line typing (the typed letters appear in multiple lines simultaneously).

Comment: @denim Yeah, you're right. Well, hopefully someone else can give us an answer.

Comment: @denim It works for multiline typing in Qt Creator 3.4.2

Comment: What if we want to select positions in the code with mouse?